# Using a HashSet to canonicalize objects in Rust

Tags: rust, hashset, canonicalization

As an educational exercise, I'm looking at porting [cvs-fast-export](https://gitlab.com/esr/cvs-fast-export) to Rust.

Its basic mode of operation is to parse a number of CVS master files into a intermediate form, and then to analyse the intermediate form with the goal of transforming it into a git fast-export stream.

One of the things that is done when parsing is to convert common parts of the intermediate form into a canonical representation. A motivating example is commit authors. A CVS repository may have hundreds of thousands of individual file commits, but probably less than a thousand authors. So an interning table is used when parsing where you input the author as you parse it from the file and it will give you a pointer to a canonical version, creating a new one if it hasn't seen it before. (I've heard this called atomizing or interning too). This pointer then gets stored on the intermediate object.

My first attempt to do something similar in Rust attempted to use a `HashSet` as the interning table. Note this uses CVS version numbers rather than authors, this is just a sequence of digits such as 1.2.3.4, represented as a `Vec`.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Hash, Clone)]
struct CvsNumber(Vec<u16>);

fn intern<T:Eq + Hash + Clone>(set: &mut HashSet<T>, item: T) -> &T {
    let dupe = item.clone();
    if !set.contains(&item) {
        set.insert(item);
    }
    set.get(&dupe).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let mut set: HashSet<CvsNumber> = HashSet::new();
    let c1 = CvsNumber(vec![1, 2]);
    let c2 = intern(&mut set, c1);
    let c3 = CvsNumber(vec![1, 2]);
    let c4 = intern(&mut set, c3);
}
```

This fails with `error[E0499]: cannot borrow 'set' as mutable more than once at a time`. This is fair enough, `HashSet` doesn't guarantee references to its keys will be valid if you add more items after you have obtained a reference. The C version is careful to guarantee this. To get this guarantee, I think the `HashSet` should be over `Box<T>`. However I can't explain the lifetimes for this to the borrow checker.

The ownership model I am going for here is that the interning table owns the canonical versions of the data, and hands out references. The references should be valid as long the interning table exists. We should be able to add new things to the interning table without invalidating the old references. I think the root of my problem is that I'm confused how to write the interface for this contract in a way consistent with the Rust ownership model.

Solutions I see with my limited Rust knowledge are:

1. Do two passes, build a `HashSet` on the first pass, then freeze it and use references on the second pass. This means additional temporary storage (sometimes substantial).
2. Unsafe

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I somewhat disagree with @Shepmaster on the use of `unsafe` here.

While *right now* it does not cause issue, should someone decide in the future to change the use of `HashSet` to include some pruning (for example, to only ever keep a hundred authors in there), then `unsafe` will bite you sternly.

In the absence of a strong performance reason, I would simply use a `Rc<XXX>`. You can alias it easily enough: `type InternedXXX = Rc<XXX>;`.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Hash, Clone)]
struct CvsNumber(Rc<Vec<u16>>);

fn intern<T:Eq + Hash + Clone>(set: &mut HashSet<T>, item: T) -> T {
    if !set.contains(&item) {
        let dupe = item.clone();
        set.insert(dupe);
        item
    } else {
        set.get(&item).unwrap().clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut set: HashSet<CvsNumber> = HashSet::new();
    let c1 = CvsNumber(Rc::new(vec![1, 2]));
    let c2 = intern(&mut set, c1);
    let c3 = CvsNumber(Rc::new(vec![1, 2]));
    let c4 = intern(&mut set, c3);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify on *who* might change `HashSet`? I don't suppose you mean that the implementer of `HashSet` would change (there's not much we can do about that, anyway). If you mean the *use* of `HashSet` inside the interner, then yes. That's why I always advocate the use of comments next to each `unsafe` to document it. I thought about using `Rc`, but didn't like the interaction with the forced allocation. You can't intern `&[u16]`, for example.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Note that I say *change the use of `HashSet`*, by which I mean that either the OP or some other future contributor might break the invariant that data is never removed from the set. As for commenting the use of the `unsafe`, this is a commendable idea, however one might not think of looking into the `intern` method when adding another method... and one might misunderstand or misinterpret comments, too. In *this specific* example, it is simple enough certainly, but I would prefer avoiding cultivating a culture of "just use `unsafe` here".

Comment: To clarify my previous comment for future readers, I dislike this solution in *this* case because it requires *extraneous allocations*. Specifically, every string that wants to be interned must first be allocated, then a hashmap checked, then either stored or deallocated. The total number of allocations over the lifetime of the program is the *same*, but duplicates are deallocated much earlier, so the maximum memory usage at any given time is lower. There is also some amount of runtime overhead to increment / decrement the refcount. If those limitations are OK, this is a perfect solution!

Comment: I narrowly missed writing this myself. I missed the point of `Rc` is that you can return `T` instead of `&T`. I've marked this answer as correct, even though @Shepmaster has more strictly answered my question as you are right that this should be my first solution, and I should only go for the unsafe version after profiling. It is nice to know both options exist.

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis is correct. The ultimate issue is that when modifying the `HashSet`, the compiler cannot guarantee that the mutations will not affect the existing allocations. Indeed, in general they *might* affect them, unless you add another layer of indirection, as you have identified.

This is a prime example of a place that `unsafe` is useful. You, the programmer, can assert that the code will only ever be used in a particular way, and that particular way will allow the variable to be stable through any mutations. You can use the type system and module visibility to help enforce these conditions.

Note that `String` already introduces a heap allocation. So long as you don't change the `String` once it's allocated, you don't need an extra `Box`.

Something like this seems like an OK start:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashSet, mem};

struct EasyInterner(RefCell<HashSet<String>>);

impl EasyInterner {
    fn new() -> Self {
        EasyInterner(RefCell::new(HashSet::new()))
    }

    fn intern<'a>(&'a self, s: &str) -> &'a str {
        let mut set = self.0.borrow_mut();

        if !set.contains(s) {
            set.insert(s.into());
        }

        let interned = set.get(s).expect("Impossible missing string");

        // TODO: Document the pre- and post-conditions that the code must
        // uphold to make this unsafe code valid instead of copying this
        // from Stack Overflow without reading it
        unsafe { mem::transmute(interned.as_str()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = EasyInterner::new();

    let a = i.intern("hello");
    let b = i.intern("world");
    let c = i.intern("hello");

    // Still strings
    assert_eq!(a, "hello");
    assert_eq!(a, c);
    assert_eq!(b, "world");

    // But with the same address
    assert_eq!(a.as_ptr(), c.as_ptr());
    assert!(a.as_ptr() != b.as_ptr());

    // This shouldn't compile; a cannot outlive the interner
    // let x = {
    //     let i = EasyInterner::new();
    //     let a = i.intern("hello");
    //     a
    // };

    let the_pointer;
    let i = {
        let i = EasyInterner::new();
        {
            // Introduce a scope to contstrain the borrow of `i` for `s`
            let s = i.intern("inner");
            the_pointer = s.as_ptr();
        }
        i // moving i to a new location
          // All outstanding borrows are invalidated
    };

    // but the data is still allocated
    let s = i.intern("inner");
    assert_eq!(the_pointer, s.as_ptr());
}
```

However, it may be much more expedient to use a crate like:

- [string_cache](https://crates.io/crates/string_cache), which has the collective brainpower of the Servo project behind it.
- [typed-arena](https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena)
- [generational-arena](https://crates.io/crates/generational-arena)

Comment: I'm torn as to which of yours and Matthieu's answers to tick. I think you have more strictly answered the question I asked, but Matthieu has given a more idiomatic rust solution, albeit with with additional overheads and safety.  Both answers make valuable contributions, I wish I could tick both.

Comment: @Laurence no worries! You are supposed to accept whichever answer best helps *you*. Upvotes are for questions and answers that were useful to *someone*. Over time, people may upvote a non-accepted answer more or less than the accepted one.

Comment: @Laurence Although I **would** say that string_cache is probably the better answer than either version of rolling your own.